# Can I use Ruby gems in Opal?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, opalrb

There's `opal-irb` and `opal-jquery` and `vienna` but is there any way to use gems directly in the browser via Opal?

Answer (score 6):

You can add a gem's `lib` path to Opal load paths by using `Opal.use_gem`

Common pitfalls are:

- use of String mutability
- relying on the difference between String and Symbol
- shelling out (``` `` ``` and `%x{}`)

Available tools to fix/workaround some of those issues are:

- stubbing files `Opal::Processor.stub_file('fileutils')`
- hiding code branches at compile time using `RUBY_ENGINE`, 
  example:

  `unless RUBY_ENGINE == 'opal'
    unparsable/breaking code here
  end`

You can look at the `opal-rspec` source code to see this stuff in action:

https://github.com/opal/opal-rspec

Comment: Hi there Elia, I'm trying to use the "faker" gem with Opal. Could you please explain with a bit more detail where should I put the "Opal.use_gem('faker')" line ? I've put it at the top of Rakefile, after "require 'opal'" but then I get ```Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'psych'``` when I run rake build..? Thank you

Comment: If you're using rails you should put it into an initializer

Comment: I am not using Rails?

Comment: I guess then it depends on how you organize your project. Anyways the code should be executed during the setup, e.g. just after requiring opal MRI/CRuby side.

Comment: My project structure is exactly the same of the basic static application example at http://opalrb.org/docs/static_applications/ and I use "Opal.use_gem('faker')" right after the require 'opal' line. Any clues?

Comment: I'd put that just after `env.append_path "app"` in the Rakefile (from http://opalrb.org/docs/static_applications/)

Comment: `builder = Opal::Builder.new; builder.path_reader.append_paths("path/to/the/gem_name/lib"); builder.build_str('require "opal"; require "gem_name"', '(inline)')`

Comment: also, from command line: `opal --include "path/to/gem/lib" --require "gem_name" --compile source.rb > app.js`

Answer (score 3):

As usual the answer is yes and no at the same time, depending on your point of view. Opal will turn your ruby (*all* of it) into JavaScript and provides an appropriate run time. If you require a gem it will be required during the compilation process and will be included into the generated JavaScript. You may freely use the generated ruby classes in your ruby code (which again ends up being compiled into JavaScript).

So you *can* require gems, but bear in mind that their requires will also be required, so will end up with a *nightmare* of a JavaScript file if you are not careful. *Technically* you are *still* not running ruby in the browser, it all had to be compiled to JavaScript for that purpose. However you *can* run the code generated from your ruby and the required gems, though it will have become JavaScript during the process (and you will have to debug it as such). There are some limitations to this approach though, you will have to bear in mind JavaScript `Number` and `String` properties (aka only immutable `String`s), but within these limits you may share your code between the server and the client.

Comment: How about gems that use `C`?

Comment: No way to have those in your browser. An alternative is to wrap NodeJS libs and replicate the gem api if you migrate some code to node.